# Programmatically hide WPF Ribbon Header

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am using VS2010's WPF Ribbon Application. Each RibbonGroup has a Header. Even If I leave the Header empty, the Ribbon will still reserve an empty space for the Header. How can I programmatically hide the header?

For instance, I have following Xaml:

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HelpTab"
                    Header="Help" FontSize="10">
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="HelpGroup"
                        Header="Help Group" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="Bold">
             <!-- ..... -->
        </ribbon:RibbonButton>
    </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

I want to programmatically hide the part (header text and height space) marked by red rectangle.

[image]

I'm looking for a C# code behind solution where I could hide the text and the space (height) the header takes up all together, something such as below:

```
// of course, this doesn't work    
HelpTab.HeaderStyle.Visibility = Visibility.Hide
```

Comment: I am looking for solution other than a hack - e.g. using margin to hide it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the `VisualTreeHelper`. Just go set the row `MinHeight` to 0 :

```
private void RibbonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DependencyObject groupBorder = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Foobar, 0);
  Grid groupMainGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(groupBorder , 0) as Grid;
  if (groupMainGrid != null)
  {
    groupMainGrid.RowDefinitions[2].MinHeight = 0;
  }
}
```

This is assuming that you didn't set the `Header` property. The height of the row is set by default to `Auto`. So if you set the `Header` property, you might as well set the `Height` to 0 :

```
groupMainGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create stack panel instead of ribbon group.